# Javascript: How to write this drop event in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This works:

```
var picdrag = document.getElementById('picdrag');
picdrag.addEventListener('drop', picSelect, false);
function picSelect(e) {
    var pics = e.dataTransfer.files;
}
```

This doesn't:

```
$('#picdrag').on('drop', function(e) {picSelect(e);});
function picSelect(e) {
    var pics = e.dataTransfer.files;
}
```

because it reports an error `'e.dataTransfer is undefined'`. I hate it when I don't know why something works or doesn't work. This is specific to the drop event, like jQuery handles it differently.

Comment: Use `console.log(e)` to see data

Comment: I updated my answer, according to the docs it should work

Comment: [This](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/10756) may also be of interest.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try:

```
var pics = e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.files;
```

From the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/):

> Certain events may have properties specific to them. Those can be
>   accessed as properties of the event.originalEvent object. To make
>   special properties available in all event objects, they can be added
>   to the jQuery.event.props array. This is not recommended, since it
>   adds overhead to every event delivered by jQuery.

There is also an example that should be of interest:

```
// add the dataTransfer property for use with the native `drop` event  
// to capture information about files dropped into the browser window
jQuery.event.props.push("dataTransfer");
```

Comment: I would up-vote this by 100 if I could. Adding the "on" using jQuery isn't the same as the DOM addEventListener... I searched everywhere and found this help on Stack Overflow. Love this site.

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#picdrag').on('drop', picSelect);
var picSelect = function(e) {
    var pics = e.dataTransfer.files;
};
```

Comment: But... but... why? What's the ******* difference? And it doesn't work... works even less than before since inside picSelect I have another function call that calls stopPropagation() and preventDefault() and those have no effect now.

Comment: @DMIL: Maybe that's something you should have but in the original question? ;)